# ABS and VSA lights on

Tags: honda, brakes, civic, abs

On my 2006 Honda Civic 1.8 liter car.

The VSA and ABS lights are on when the brake is applied.

The car doesn't stop and makes a judder and a sound like grinding metal. The brake pads where changed as we thought this might be the problem. The old pads where still very meaty, now the problem is progressively getting worse.

What could be the problem that is creating this condition?

Is there a way that I can get some error codes to further diagnose this problem?

Comment: Can you raise the car and target where the sound is coming from while rotating the wheel? Also, how old are your rotors? If you've literally begun to wear them through you could get the symptoms you're describing. In any case, don't drive it. Take it to a mechanic if you can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

That is your stability assist and abs. do you have brake fluid in the reservoir?

does the brake go to the floor?

your old pads should be fine and you can keep them for later if you want.

can you scan the computer for the codes it is throwing? you might be able to borrow a scan tool. These codes will help or at least may help find the answer.

where does the grinding metal sound come from? is it a squeal or a gravelly grind sound? or is it more of a fast hammering sound?

first check the fluid I will update this with more info when I have a free moment. This certainly sounds like an abs issue.